# Big Two's classification according to game theory

Tags: game-theory, card-games

Is the game Big Two, as described in https://www.pagat.com/climbing/bigtwo.html,
classified as:

- a game of *perfect* or *imperfect information*?
- *deterministic* or *stochastic*?

EDIT:
I am fairly certain it is a game of imperfect information; however, i have doubts about it being deterministic or stochastic. The game starts of by shuffling a deck and distributing the cards by the four players, 13 to each. From a game theory perspective, and considering the extensive (tree) representation of the game, one could imagine an initial node belonging to chance, representing the state before the cards are handed out to the players, and with a single action available; handing out the cards would then correspond to executing that action, which would be a non-deterministic action, as the distribution of the cards among the players is random. This would make the game a stochastic game. However, I'm not certain this interpretation is correct. In particular, I'm not sure if it is correct to consider a node representing the state of the game before the cards are handed out to the players.

Comment: What do you think? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I've responded by editing my question. Thank you, I initially tried to keep the question as concise as possible.